# ios cocos2d 2.0 what use instead of glNormalPointer

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

In my project i need rotate sprite in 3d with perspective.
all transforms work fine(used kmGLRotatef(angle,1, 0, 0);) except perspective.
I found some old code:

```
-(void) draw
{
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY); 
glNormalPointer (GL_FLOAT, 0, Normals); 

[super draw];   

glDisableClientState( GL_NORMAL_ARRAY ); 
}
```

but I can't find any info on what to use instead of glNormalPointer and glEnableClientState;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocos2D 2.0 now defaults to using 2D projection. It may be as simple as switching back to 3D projection. The code to switch projection is found in your project's AppDelegate:

```
    [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection2D];
//  [director setProjection:kCCDirectorProjection3D];
```